# Advice on setting up RabbitMQ/Bunny in virtual environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, bunny

I am attempting to test the functionality of RabbitMQ and Bunny in my local environment as a proof of concept. We are currently using Beaneater/Beanstalk and wishing to change. I am using vagrant for my local environment but cant seem to find a suitable VM.

Can anyone point me in the direct of a good tutorial which gives step by step instruction as the multitude I have attempted all seem to take different approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you considered docker, instead?

I used to do vagrant and other types of virtual machines for services I need, but now I'm using docker for just about everything like this.

Download and install docker from http://docker.com (get the latest Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, or Docker Engine for linux - not the "docker toolbox" that they link to on the homepage)

Once you have docker installed, you can download rabbitmq image, and create a container:

```
docker pull rabbitmq:management
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --name rmq rabbitmq:management
```

now when you need rabbitmq running, you just do this:

```
docker start rmq
```

and when you don't need it running:

```
docker stop rmq
```

You can access RMQ through `localhost` with the port forwarding that this setup, for both rabbitmq clients and the web management interface.

more information about this docker image for rabbitmq is found here: https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/